Create new file with XML data from original file based on criteria
On the page I have it loading content from an XML file.
There is then a form which displays entries from this XML file based on the category name matching the $_GET['cat'] value.
The form then allows me to edit 2 values ( min & nominal ).
On submission it saves the XML content with new values to a file, however I only want it to save the data if the category name matches the $_GET['cat'] value.
I have tried few things but it still keeps saving all of the content from the original XML with updated values, rather than only the data that matches the category name.
Heres my code :
if(isset($_POST))
{
    $row = array();
    $r = 0;
    $catName = str_replace('.xml','',$_POST['catFile']); // Add change
    foreach($_POST['row'] as $row)
    {
        $catFile = $_POST['catFile'];
        $ufile = simplexml_load_file('newTypes2.xml');
        foreach($ufile->type as $type)
        {
          if($type->category['name'] == $catName)
          {
            if($type['name'] == $_POST['item'][$r])
            {
                $type->nominal = $_POST['nominal'][$r];
                $type->min = $_POST['min'][$r];
                break;
            }
            file_put_contents($catFile, $ufile->asXML());
          }
        }
        $r++;
    }
}

Heres the form :
if(!file_exists('newTypes2.xml'))
{
 $xml = simplexml_load_file('types.xml');   
} else {
$xml = simplexml_load_file('newTypes2.xml');
}
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
$cat = $_GET['cat'];

$i = 0;
$count = count($xml->type);
echo '<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">';
foreach($xml->type as $type)
{
    if($cat == 'weapons')
    {
        if($type->category['name'] == "weapons")
        {
        $cnt = 0;
        echo '<div class="form-group"><input type="hidden" name="row[]" value="'.$cnt.'"><input type="hidden" name="item[]" value="'.$type['name'].'">';
        echo '<div class="col-md-4"><strong>'.$type['name'].'</strong></div> <div class="col-md-4">Nominal : <input class="form-control" type="text" value="'.$type->nominal.'" name="nominal[]"></div><div class="col-md-4">Minimum : <input type="text" class="form-control" value="'.$type->min.'" name="min[]"></div>';
        echo '</div>';
        $cnt++;
        }
    }
    if($cat == 'tools')
    {
        if($type->category['name'] == "tools")
        {
        $cnt = 0;
        echo '<div class="form-group"><input type="hidden" name="row[]" value="'.$cnt.'"><input type="hidden" name="item[]" value="'.$type['name'].'">';
        echo '<div class="col-md-4"><strong>'.$type['name'].'</strong></div> <div class="col-md-4">Nominal : <input class="form-control" type="text" value="'.$type->nominal.'" name="nominal[]"></div><div class="col-md-4">Minimum : <input type="text" class="form-control" value="'.$type->min.'" name="min[]"></div>';
        echo '</div>';
        $cnt++;
        }
    }
    if($cat == 'clothes')
    {
        if($type->category['name'] == "clothes")
        {
        $cnt = 0;
        echo '<div class="form-group"><input type="hidden" name="row[]" value="'.$cnt.'"><input type="hidden" name="item[]" value="'.$type['name'].'">';
        echo '<div class="col-md-4"><strong>'.$type['name'].'</strong></div> <div class="col-md-4">Nominal : <input class="form-control" type="text" value="'.$type->nominal.'" name="nominal[]"></div><div class="col-md-4">Minimum : <input type="text" class="form-control" value="'.$type->min.'" name="min[]"></div>';
        echo '</div>';
        $cnt++;
        }
    }
}
if(isset($_GET['cat']))
{
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="catFile" value="'.$_GET['cat'].'.xml">';
   echo '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-info">CHANGE</button></form>';
}

Heres some sample XML data :
<types>
<type name="AK74_WoodBttstck">
        <nominal>5</nominal>
        <lifetime>14400</lifetime>
        <restock>0</restock>
        <min>2</min>
        <quantmin>-1</quantmin>
        <quantmax>-1</quantmax>
        <cost>100</cost>
        <flags count_in_cargo="0" count_in_hoarder="0" count_in_map="1" count_in_player="0" crafted="0" deloot="0"/>
        <category name="weapons"/>
        <usage name="Military"/>
    </type>
    <type name="AKM">
        <nominal>1</nominal>
        <lifetime>7200</lifetime>
        <restock>3600</restock>
        <min>1</min>
        <quantmin>30</quantmin>
        <quantmax>80</quantmax>
        <cost>100</cost>
        <flags count_in_cargo="0" count_in_hoarder="0" count_in_map="1" count_in_player="0" crafted="0" deloot="0"/>
        <category name="weapons"/>
        <usage name="ContaminatedArea"/>
    </type>
    <type name="AKS74U">
        <nominal>17</nominal>
        <lifetime>28800</lifetime>
        <restock>0</restock>
        <min>12</min>
        <quantmin>30</quantmin>
        <quantmax>80</quantmax>
        <cost>100</cost>
        <flags count_in_cargo="0" count_in_hoarder="0" count_in_map="1" count_in_player="0" crafted="0" deloot="0"/>
        <category name="weapons"/>
        <usage name="Military"/>
        <value name="Tier2"/>
        <value name="Tier3"/>
        <value name="Tier4"/>
    </type>
<type name="SpearBone">
        <nominal>0</nominal>
        <lifetime>14400</lifetime>
        <restock>0</restock>
        <min>0</min>
        <quantmin>-1</quantmin>
        <quantmax>-1</quantmax>
        <cost>100</cost>
        <flags count_in_cargo="0" count_in_hoarder="0" count_in_map="1" count_in_player="0" crafted="1" deloot="0"/>
        <category name="tools"/>
    </type>
    <type name="SpearStone">
        <nominal>0</nominal>
        <lifetime>14400</lifetime>
        <restock>0</restock>
        <min>0</min>
        <quantmin>-1</quantmin>
        <quantmax>-1</quantmax>
        <cost>100</cost>
        <flags count_in_cargo="0" count_in_hoarder="0" count_in_map="1" count_in_player="0" crafted="1" deloot="0"/>
        <category name="tools"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Splint">
        <nominal>0</nominal>
        <lifetime>14400</lifetime>
        <restock>0</restock>
        <min>0</min>
        <quantmin>-1</quantmin>
        <quantmax>-1</quantmax>
        <cost>100</cost>
        <flags count_in_cargo="0" count_in_hoarder="0" count_in_map="1" count_in_player="0" crafted="1" deloot="0"/>
        <category name="clothes"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Splint_Applied">
        <nominal>0</nominal>
        <lifetime>3</lifetime>
        <restock>0</restock>
        <min>0</min>
        <quantmin>-1</quantmin>
        <quantmax>-1</quantmax>
        <cost>100</cost>
        <flags count_in_cargo="0" count_in_hoarder="0" count_in_map="1" count_in_player="0" crafted="1" deloot="0"/>
        <category name="clothes"/>
    </type>
    <type name="SportGlasses_Black">
        <nominal>20</nominal>
        <lifetime>14400</lifetime>
        <restock>0</restock>
        <min>10</min>
        <quantmin>-1</quantmin>
        <quantmax>-1</quantmax>
        <cost>100</cost>
        <flags count_in_cargo="0" count_in_hoarder="0" count_in_map="1" count_in_player="0" crafted="0" deloot="0"/>
        <category name="clothes"/>
        <tag name="shelves"/>
        <usage name="Industrial"/>
        <usage name="Town"/>
        <usage name="Village"/>
        <usage name="Office"/>
        <usage name="School"/>
    </type>
</types>

Edit :
Should just add, if $cat='tools' for example,instead of it only saving items with 
it stores ALL the type items
I previously wanted to have the script create individual XML files based on the category name.
If anyone can help me figure that out instead that would be a lot easier

You are using a variable before you define it: $catName = str_replace('.xml','',$catFile); happens before $catFile = $_POST['catFile'];

As a side note, a golden rule of web programming: never trust any input from the browser. Taking a filename directly from $_POST leaves you open to someone manipulating the form and causing you to display or overwrite your source code, settings, or even system files on the server. You need to carefully whitelist what values can be provided.

Its only myself using this locally, also just fixed the error you mentioned, $catName = str_replace('.xml','',$_POST'[catFile']);
Still posts the entire XML content from original file

To debug this, don't write a new XML, just echo or better var_dump values so you can see what is truly in there. Start with foreach($_POST['row'] as $row). Inside of that loop just var_dump($row);, nothing else. Then move on to foreach($ufile->type as $type), and var_dump($type);, nothing else. Go into your if statements then and inspect individual fields and/or variables.

@ChrisHaas - Thank you ! For one $_POST['row'] was only displaying the integer value. I changed it to foreach($_POST as $row) and now the filtering works when saving, however its not saving all items in the selected category.
Its doing a couple and then stopping.
I've tried repositioning the file_put as well but then it repeats previous entries as well as the new entry

You are calling simplexml_load_file each time in the loop, and then I think you are writing to another file, so only the last would win. You should only need to call simplexml_load_file once, then loop over $_POST and the XML as you are, and then write to disk once done.

Perfect ! Thank you.. I wouldn't have noticed that.. works great now thanks

Converting SimpleXMLElement to JSON using json_encode() will often result in data loss. This serializes the debug output of a SimpleXMLElement instance.
Access/Manipulate XML using an XML API. I prefer DOM+Xpath. This allows to target specific nodes and any kinds of manipulation (SimpleXML is an abstraction and limited).
For DOM first create and load the document.
$original = __DIR__.'/types.xml';
$edited = __DIR__.'/newTypes.xml';
$allowedCategories = ['weapons', 'tools', 'clothes'];

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load(file_exists($edited) ? $edited : $original);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

The Xpath instance can be used to fetch nodes (as node lists) or scalar values
from the document. This is how the form output could look:
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="./" method="post">
      <?php
        // iterate the "type" elements
        foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/types/type') as $typeNode) {
          // fetch the first "name" attribute of the "category" element as a string
          $category = $xpath->evaluate('string(category/@name)', $typeNode);
          if (!in_array($category, $allowedCategories)) {
            continue;
          }
          // read the name attribute of the current "type" element
          $itemName = $typeNode->getAttribute('name');
          // read the "nominal" child element as a number, cast to int
          $nominal =  (int)$xpath->evaluate('number(nominal)', $typeNode);
          // read the "min" child element as a number, cast to int
          $min =  (int)$xpath->evaluate('number(min)', $typeNode);
          // prepare the parameter name prefix - add "[someKey]" for each field
          $fieldPrefix = 'items['.htmlspecialchars($itemName).']';
          ?>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4"><strong><?=htmlspecialchars($itemName)?></strong></div>
            <div class="col-md-4">Nominal : <input name="<?=$fieldPrefix?>[nominal]" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?=$nominal?>"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4">Minimum : <input name="<?=$fieldPrefix?>[min]" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?=$min?>"></div>
          </div>
          <?php
        }
      ?>
      <button>Save</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

PHP will parse a parameter name like items[someName1][someKey1] into a nested associative array structure. This allows to remove the hidden fields and reduce the complexity.
<?=...> is the PHP short tag syntax. It was added to make PHP templates more readable.
Now if you submit the form $_POST will contain a nested structure that you can iterate (the following code should go before the form output).
$modified = false;
// check for the "items" parameter
if (isset($_POST['items']) && is_array($_POST['items'])) {
  // iterate it
  foreach ($_POST['items'] as $name => $data) {
    // fetch the "type" element with the matching "name" attribute
    $typeNode = $xpath->evaluate('/types/type[@name="'.$name.'"]')[0];
    // if found
    if ($typeNode) {
      // iterate the properties, use a whitelist
      foreach (['min', 'nominal'] as $propertyName) {
        // fetch the property node
        $propertyNode = $xpath->evaluate($propertyName, $typeNode)[0];
        // if node exists, data exists and the values are different
        if (
          $propertyNode &&
          $data[$propertyName] &&
          $propertyNode->textContent !== $data[$propertyName]
        ) {
          // update node content with parameter data
          $propertyNode->textContent = $data[$propertyName];
          $modified = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // if a node was modified, save the document
  if ($modified) {
    $document->save($edited);
  }
}

